Flutter custom phone number input
I'm having a problem trying to customize the phone number input to look like the one in the design.
I'm using the intl phone number input package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input.
I would be glad if you can help with this.
My design: https://i.sstatic.net/QsMrcRVn.png
My input phone number: https://i.sstatic.net/z1WhzvM5.jpg
This is my code:
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
      onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber phone) {
        controller.onChangePhone(phone);
      },
      onInputValidated: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          validPhone = value;
        });
      },
      selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
          leadingPadding: defaultSpace,
          selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.DIALOG,
          setSelectorButtonAsPrefixIcon: true,
          useBottomSheetSafeArea: true),
      searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: strings.registration_phone_country,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.search),
      ),
      ignoreBlank: false,
      locale: '${Get.locale}',
      autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      selectorTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      initialValue: null,
      textFieldController: phoneController,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        color: phoneController.text.isEmpty
            ? ComponentColors.secondaryColor
            : Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      ),
      inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: strings.hint_phone,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        fillColor: ComponentColors.overlayColor,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: dPaddingX0_5,
          horizontal: dPadding,
        ),
        filled: true,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
      ),
      inputBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      errorMessage: strings.registration_error_phone,
    );


The library doesn't seem to support that design directly, but you can achieve the desired look by placing the InternationalPhoneNumberInput inside a Stack with a Row containing two Container widgets. To make this work, you need to disable filled: true in the inputDecoration and adjust the width of the first Container. Here’s how you can do it:
 IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                width: 70,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius:
                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
            onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber phone) {
              controller.onChangePhone(phone);
            },
            onInputValidated: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                validPhone = value;
              });
            },
            selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
                leadingPadding: defaultSpace,
                selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.DIALOG,
                setSelectorButtonAsPrefixIcon: true,
                useBottomSheetSafeArea: true),
            searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: strings.registration_phone_country,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.search),
            ),
            ignoreBlank: false,
            locale: '${Get.locale}',
            autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            selectorTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            initialValue: null,
            textFieldController: phoneController,
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: phoneController.text.isEmpty
                  ? ComponentColors.secondaryColor
                  : Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            ),
            inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: strings.hint_phone,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              fillColor: ComponentColors.overlayColor,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: dPaddingX0_5,
                horizontal: dPadding,
              ),
              //filled: true,
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
            inputBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            errorMessage: strings.registration_error_phone,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),


Wow thats it. Thank you!
